# Class for New Tkinter Window gives TypeEror: CreateSlider() missing 1 required positional Argument: 'SlideAsk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a GUI which opens at specific moments and retrieves some questionnaire data. There are specific types of questionnaire windows, so I decided to make a class for it. When using it, I stumble upon the following error:
TypeEror: CreateSlider() missing 1 required positional Argument: 'SlideAsk'

This is my first attempt at using a class like this so I am not certain if I did something fundamentally wrong or that its a minor issue. Other fixes proposed on the forum did not seem to work.

```
class Questionnaire:

    global startrow,startcol
    startrow  = 1
    startcol  = 0

    def __init__(self,width,height,IntroMessage,RadioAsk,Choose,SlideAsk):
        global startrow,startcol

        width          = width
        height        = height
        IntroMessage   = IntroMessage
        RadioAsk       = RadioAsk
        Choose         = Choose 
        SlideAsk       = SlideAsk  

        self = CTkToplevel()
        self.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")
        self.title("Questionnaire")
        self.frame  = CTkFrame(master=self)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe", padx=20, pady=20)
        
        #try:
        Intro = CTkLabel(self.frame, text= IntroMessage)
        Intro.grid(row=startrow, column=startcol, columnspan=1, pady=20, padx=20, sticky="w")
        startrow +=1
        #except:
            #pass
                #try:
        CreateSlider(SlideAsk)
        #except:
            #pass

        #try:
        CreateRadio(RadioAsk,Choose,startrow,startcol)             
        #except:
            #pass
    
def CreateRadio(self,title,Choose):

    label_Type = CTkLabel(master=self.frame,text=title)
    label_Type.grid(row=startrow, column=startcol, columnspan=1, pady=0, padx=20, sticky="w")
    startrow +=1

    answer = StringVar()
    answer.set(Choose[len(Choose)])

    for text, mode in Choose:
        RB = Radiobutton(self.frame, text=text, variable = answer, value = mode)
        RB.grid(pady=5,padx=10,sticky="w")
        startrow +=1


def CreateSlider(self,SlideAsk):
    for q in SlideAsk:
        label_Question = CTkLabel(master=self.frame,text= q)
        label_Question.grid(row=startrow, column=0, columnspan=1, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="w")
        startrow+=1

        slider_Question = CTkSlider(master=self.frame,from_=1,to=5,number_of_steps=4)
        slider_Question.grid(row=startrow, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")



def Open_Break():     
    Questionnaire(width = 400,
        height         = 600,
        IntroMessage   = "Please, answer the questions below",
        RadioAsk       = "First question",
        Choose         = [
            ("Opt1","One"),
            ("Opt2","Two"),
            ("Opt3","Three"),
            ("Opt4","Four")],
        SlideAsk       = [
            "This is the first question.",
            "This is the second question.",
            "This is the third question."])
```

Comment: Is the indentation of your example accurate? `def CreateRadio` and `def CreateSlider` should be indented more.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley. Was right. Those 3 functions should be inside class Questionnaire:. When you put in def __init__. You should add self.CreateSlider(SlideAsk).

Comment: At first I did have them in the class, but that did not seem to work either. When I do, I get the error "CTkToplevel" object has no attribute "CreateSlider". DO I have to put 'self' in front of all elements in the separate functions too?

Comment: You should not overwrite `self` with an instance of `CTkToplevel`.  The line `self = CTkToplevel()` should be something like `self.win = CTkToplevel()`.  And then replace the `master=self` to `master=self.win`.